# How to prevent a Lua file closing when I press enter?

Tags: input, lua, file-io

I have a block of code in sublime text, and whenever I press enter on the Lua file its connected to, the file closes, so I can't enter input. The code is below.

```
io.write("name?")
local name = io.read()
io.write("hello " .. name)
```

I expected it to print "hello " and then whatever input was entered, but the file closes instead.

Comment: > "When called without arguments, it uses a default format that reads the next line"
(excerpt from Lua 5..4.4 documentation)

Comment: `io.read()` only reads one line, so if you press Enter before typing anything else, you're giving it an empty line.

Comment: Try `io.write("hello " .. name .. "\n")`.

Comment: Also ```io.read()``` can be directly in ```io.write()``` and/or ```format()``` - XTended Version: ```io.write(("%s\n%s "):format(_VERSION, "Name?")) io.write(("%s %s\n"):format("Hello", io.read()))```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but its doing the exact same thing. I believe I have set up Lua wrong, but I have no idea what to do or how to fix it.

Comment: @shadowpig88 what os are you using ? how are you launching the above code ?

Comment: @tteixeira I am using windows 11. I followed this link [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoERwONu8rc&t=1s&ab_channel=%E3%80%88CODEBLUE%E3%80%89) to set up my Lua. He uses luaforwindows and sublime text.

Comment: Try to append final line `io.read()` to the script

Comment: If you execute the code like in the video you linked, the windows' cmd opens only to execute your program. Upon script completion, it closes.
As @ESkri said, since io.write is non-blocking, it does print what you'd asked for but terminate immediately, closing the cmd.
You could add an io.read() at the end of your program. This way, cmd won't shut until you press enter.